# Regex - Blacklist all emails Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a regex formula in Javascript to detect all emails?

It needs to be foolproof as much as possible.

`\w+.+([@]|[at]\b).+([.]|[dot]\b).+`

Test cases:

```
hello@yahoo.com
he kl @yah oo. com
hello @ yahoo.com
he l o at yahoo.com
hello at yahoo . com
hello at yahoo dot com
hello (at) yahoo . com
hello @ yahoo.com
hello @ yahoo.c o m
hello a t y a h o o . c o m reretewt
2132412 @yahoo.com kkmmkmkmkmkm
hello a. t oo. tehereom
hello at yahoo dot fine
testing at yahoo. ru
123 @yahoo.com
123 @ yahoo.com
testing at yah . c o m #positive msdjsndj #negative
There was a time that i was fine at home. Computer there lol. #negative
A white brown fox jumps over the wall at then at dot com #negative
hello @ yahoo.com
```

Comment: https://emailregex.com/

Comment: Such a regex will match a _lot_ of false positives. Plus I suppose that if people write their emails in such a hard-to-parse way, it could mean that they don't want their emails to be parsed in the first place?

Comment: @sp00m, yes, for example, if we want to block out emails from a live-chat to prevent exchanging of emails?

Comment: _“to prevent exchanging of emails”_ - there is probably close to no way that you will be able to handle _all_ possible cases correctly with regex, without mangling _proper_ conversations all the time. You basically want an AI, not regex.

Comment: @CBroe I understand that, and it definitely wont be fail-safe, but something that covers common test cases like the examples above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting browsers to detect correct emails, you can use the implemented regex. An example:

```js
let testcases_str = `hello@yahoo.com
he kl @yah oo. com
hello @ yahoo.com
he l o at yahoo.com
hello at yahoo . com
hello at yahoo dot com
hello (at) yahoo . com
hello @ yahoo.com
hello @ yahoo.c o m
hello a t y a h o o . c o m reretewt
2132412 @yahoo.com kkmmkmkmkmkm
hello a. t oo. tehereom
hello at yahoo dot fine
testing at yahoo. ru
123 @yahoo.com
123 @ yahoo.com
testing at yah . c o m #positive msdjsndj #negative
There was a time that i was fine at home. Computer there lol. #negative
A white brown fox jumps over the wall at then at dot com #negative
hello @ yahoo.com`;
let testcases = testcases_str.split(/\r?\n/);

function email_validity(email) {
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'email');
  input.setAttribute('value', email);
  return input.checkValidity();
}

for (let i in testcases) {
  let testcase = testcases[i];
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = (email_validity(testcase) ? '<b style="color:green;">&check;</b>' : '<b style="color:red;">&times;</b>') +' '+ testcase;
  document.querySelector('#result').appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

Comment: Well, that doesnt really help in my use case. We want to be able to detect true negative cases as well. For example, if we want to blacklist emails from being used in a live-chat app.